# Condition in where clause of a select statement

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, t-sql, postgresql-9.2

Suppose I have a select statement:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE a=a or b=b and c=c
```

Does the conditions are evaluated as below:

`1->a=a
 2->b=b
 3->b=b and c=c
 4->a=a or b=b and c=c`

I am having some confusion.

Comment: Why add vendor specific tags? This matter for sure is vendor agnostic so `sql` tag would be enough.

Answer (score 5):

[`and` has higher precedence](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/operator-precedence.html). It is the same as

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE 
WHERE a=a or (b=b and c=c)
```

The query returns all record where **either**

```
a=a
```

**or**

```
b=b AND c=c
```

Comment: can you list the steps without the bracket ?

Comment: SELECT * FROM TABLE 
WHERE a=a or b=b and c=c , for this one can you tell me the answer ? that is without the bracket

Comment: It is the same as without the brackets. `and` binds more than `or`.

Answer (score -1):

First it evaluates AND and then OR. So if a=a no matter what's the rest.

It means AND has higher priority. when the `a=a or b=b and c=c` condition is calculated in fact the first part (a=a) is checked and if it's true no matter what's the value of rest
true or (any value) = true

Can't you add brackets where you need?

Comment: Please expand your answer. With over 1000 answers you sure can do better.